# A very, very long riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Hello there! How do you do?
>   What am I? Oh, have no clue?,
>   but I still reside in you!
>   Let's just say I am your glue.
>   I'm not a one, let's say "a crew",
>   read my name and you will "whoo",
>   my size is small, I'll be true,
>   but I'm the longest, I bet you knew.

HINT 1:

> I am THE longest.

HINT 2:

> First 2 lines are just fillers

Comment: Just a guess: does the correct answer have "whoo" pronounced in it? This would make the 6th line literal, as saying the answer would include saying "whoo."

Comment: No, the name doesn't contain any "whoo"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks a lot to your hints and Aggie's answer I'd say you are

> Titin or connectin

Hello there! How do you do? What am I? Oh, have no clue?,

> Okay I don't know how to fit there, I guess you could say I really have no clue.

but I still reside in you!

> Titin is a protein in humans (encoded by the TTN gene gotta ask Wikipedia what it is...)

Let's just say I am your glue.

> It connects the Z line to the M line in the sarcomere. (here again, I'm gonna ask wikipedia or google...)

I'm not alone, let's say "a crew",

> It is composed of 244 individually folded protein domains.

read my name and you will "whoo",

> The real name takes 3 hours to pronounces, so... yeah.

my size is small, I'll be true,

> Well, more or less 1µm in length

but I'm the longest, I bet you knew.

> The longest word, 189,819 letters, 3 hours to pronounces... Whoo.

And there you have it, I think it fits more or less.

Comment: I would think this was it, but no response from the OP to determine that.

Comment: YES! This is it. Its name is THE longest word ever known in the English language, and its length is THE longest known in the human body :)
Well done, mister!

Answer (score 6):

Third try....  Are you:

> Cells?

Hello there! How do you do?
What am I? Oh, have no clue?,

> OP stated this is just a filler.

but I still reside in you!

> Our body is comprised of cells. They reside within us, by making us.

Let's just say I am your glue.

> Cells make up everything, including tissues that hold us together.

I'm not alone, let's say "a crew",

> A single cell can't do much, but with a "crew", cells make up proteins, tissues, organs, etc.

read my name and you will "whoo",

> There are so many different types of cells. Not sure what makes it fit, but I'm sure something very clever could fit here.

my size is small, I'll be true,

> Cells are the building blocks of life, and generally we discuss "single cell" as being the smallest living thing.

but I'm the longest, I bet you knew.

> If we were to line up all of our cells in a single row, they would be incredibly long.

---

---

Second try. Are you:

> The genome?

Hello there! How do you do?
What am I? Oh, have no clue?,

> The human genome is so incredibly long and complex that we haven't fully discovered all that it can do.

but I still reside in you!

> Every cell in our body contains our full genome.

Let's just say I am your glue.

> The genome is what makes us who we are and "holds us together" as it were.

I'm not alone, let's say "a crew",

> Made up of DNA (which is made up of 4 bases), that is organized into 23 Chromosomes, and genes within the chromosomes.

read my name and you will "whoo",

> **Genome** -> "Ge -know - me". Leading to a, "I know who?" Or, potentially thinking of the names of genes,  **Deoxyribonucleic acid**,  **Ribonucleic acid**, and other fun names in the genome.

my size is small, I'll be true,
but I'm the longest, I bet you knew.

> The human genome is incredibly long. Though, interestingly, it is longer in some plant life (grain) than it is in humans.

---

---

*Previous attempt*
You are:

> DNA

Hello there! How do you do?
What am I? Oh, have no clue?,

> We are still discovering some of the mysteries of DNA

but I still reside in you!

> DNA is contained within every cell in your body.

Let's just say I am your glue.
I'm not alone, let's say "a crew",

> DNA is made up of 4 bases that link together, and make us who we are.

read my name and you will "whoo",

> **Deoxyribonucleic acid** is a very long name that makes most people go "huh?"

my size is small, I'll be true,
but with my length you wouldn't screw.

> DNA is very, very small, but is in a double helix form, which winds around like a screw.

Comment: This is a very nice answer... and you got more or less what I am talking about. But it's not it :) You forgot something that makes "it" not be DNA

Comment: Edited the riddle to make it "easier" XD

Comment: Ok I'll give you some hint, because I like your answers... You gave the "glue" a very "meta" meaning... And the genome is not THE longest :)

Comment: @Noldor130884 I've added a third attempt.

Comment: ...And the third attemp was also not correct :D Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Collagen

Hello there! How do you do?
What am I? Oh, have no clue?,
but I still reside in you!
Let's just say I am your glue.

> The body's cells are held together by the extracellular matrix, which contains collagen fibers

I'm not alone, let's say "a crew",

> Other proteins form the matrix, but collagen is the most prevalent

read my name and you will "whoo",

> Unsure here

my size is small, I'll be true,
but I'm the longest, I bet you knew.

> Individual fibers are small, but taken together they are part of our skin, the largest organ in our bodies

Comment: You too deserve a +1. You got something the others didn't until now. But you are still a little bit far from guessing it right :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you:

> DNA/Deoxyribonucleic Acid

Reasoning:

but I still reside in you!

> Everyone has DNA in them

Let's just say I am your glue.

> DNA makes you who you are

I'm not alone, let's say "a crew",

> There is a lot of DNA and it is made up of pieces(ATCG)

read my name and you will "whoo",

> It is a long name/hard to pronounce maybe

my size is small, I'll be true,

> DNA is very small/not visible to the naked eye

but with my length you wouldn't screw.

> Stretched out DNA is enormously long

Comment: As I already said to Aggie Kidd: very nice reply, but you didn't quite get something :P

Comment: haha yeah I hadn't seen it go up when I was typing this out, I will see if I can figure out what I missed

Comment: Edited the riddle to make it "easier" XD

Answer (score 2):

Could you be...

> Blood (cells) ?

Hello there! How do you do?

> My sample results are fine, thank you !

What am I? Oh, have no clue?,

> That one may just be a filler

but I still reside in you!

> That's where I prefer you to stay indeed !

Let's just say I am your glue.

> Blood coagulates to patch up our scratches

I'm not alone, let's say "a crew",

> Blood cells are quite numerous

read my name and you will "whoo",

> This one went above my head

my size is small, I'll be true,

> Blood cells are small.

but I'm the longest, I bet you knew.

> The circulatory system contains an incredible length of blood vessels, with the usual number in the ballpark of one hundred thousand kilometers (!)

Comment: Another nice answer, but you didn't get a couple of points. No it's not blood or blood cells.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to give it a try. Not sure if it fits completely but are you

> The small intestine?

But I still reside in you!

> Well, it does.

Let's just say I am your glue

> It refers to the absorption of glucose, which is a primarly function of the small intestine.

I'm not a one, let's say a crew

> The small intestine has three distinct regions, the duodenum, jejunum and ileum.

Read my name and you will "whoo"

> Not sure about this one yet.

My size is small, I'll be true,

But I'm the longest, I bet you knew

> It is called the **small** intestine. However, it is the longest, since the average length of the small instestine is 6.9 m in an adult male, and 7.1 m in an adult female.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is:

> backbone

because

> with crews you are the longest bone?

Maybe you mean this by "whoo":

> Whoo! Dance, dance, dance, let your backbone slip

Here:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9M7T-aEdnN8